# groovy provide context for script evaluation

Tags: groovy

Here I've got simple DSL

```
application {
    name "Template application"
}
```

Originally I used it like this

```
def application = new MainForm()
application {
    name "Template application"
}
```

where I declared `application` variable in the same file as DSL. (object `MainFrom` had overriden method `call`)

Now I decided to move my DSL outside same file into some `text` file basically

```
// application.txt
application {
    name "Template application"
}
```

And my main file have only a line

```
evaluate(new File("application.txt"))
```

But how to provide the context for evaluation? Because currently it fails because

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: application.application() is applicabe for argument types: (application$_run_closure1) values: [application$_run_closure1@5bfa9431]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as a solution I did like this

```
def application = new MainForm()
Binding binding = new Binding()
binding.setVariable("application", application)

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
    .evaluate(new File("application.txt"))
```

Though I am not sure whether it can be done better

Comment: This is how I would do it. It looks 100% correct to me.